# Show each interval (a,b) is open in the basis B

Tags: general-topology, sorgenfrey-line

I am using Topology Without Tears by Morris

Let B={[a,b)$\in R$:a<b} B is a basis for some topology $\tau$ on R,but  not the Euclidean one.

**Regardless show for each interval (a,b)is open  in (R $\tau$)**

Attempted proof

Let B be a base for $\tau$.

If for each x$\in$ (a,b)$\subseteq$ U

Let $I_n=[a,b-1/n) $

Then the union of all intervals (a,b)=$\bigcup_{n\in N}I_n$

for some
index n$\in $N and $I_n\in$ B

But x $\in $U implies x$\in I_n$ for n$ \in N$
then [x,b)$\in $(a,b) and [x,b)$\in $B

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: $\bigcup_{n\in N}I_n = (a,b)$ is not right, I think

Comment: Can you give me a good set. I got mine from another post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a<b$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $a+\frac1N<b$. Then$$\bigcup_{n\geqslant N}\left[a+\frac1n,b\right)=(a,b).$$

Comment: Thanks Jose, that is the missing part

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just say that

$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[a+\frac{b-a}{n+1}, b\right)$$

Comment: That is an interesting interval

Comment: Yep ... Divide $(a,b)$ into $n+1$ equal parts and chop off the first one $(a,a+\frac{b-a}{n+1})$, leaving the half-open rest.

Comment: Is that the whole proof in a nutshell?

Comment: It is as good as the other proofs I can see here. I just didn't want to put the uncertainty from which $n$ the interval is nonempty - decided to make it so that the intervals are nonempty from the outset (i.e. $n=1$). On the other hand, I guess the other proofs are easier to read.